lionbridge-connector on Azure Artifacts gives Dependency Error
I'm trying to migrate our Maven artifacts from Nexus to Azure Artifacts, but I've run into a problem due to the "lionbridge-connector.all.author" artefact. This artefact is zip archive, where the pom resides only within the archive. On Nexus, we were able to upload the archive as is provided, but when deploying to Azure Artifacts with "mvn deploy:deploy-file", the pom file keeps getting extracted and uploaded separately to the feed.
Because of this, when building the project, maven attempts to resolve its pom dependencies instead of treating the archive like a file.
Error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project project-3rd-party-container: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.proj.aem:project-3rd-party-container:content-package:2.18.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.adobe.cloud.translation.connector:lionbridge-connector.all.author:zip:5.1.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.adobe.cloud.translation.connector:lionbridge-connector.all.author:zip:5.1.1: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.adobe.cloud.translation.connector:lionbridge-connector:pom:5.1.1 (absent): Could not find artifact com.adobe.cloud.translation.connector:lionbridge-connector:pom:5.1.1 in azure-feed (https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-organization/project-id/_packaging/azure-feed/maven/v1)

I was unable to find a way to upload the package without the pom file and I also don't know of any way to tell maven to stop resolving the pom for this particular dependency. The parent dependency mentioned in the error "lionbridge-connector" most likely doesn't exist and isn't meant to be read. Does anyone else know of a way to solve this issue? It's been haunting me for days.
Tried uploading archive without pom file by renaming the pom file. The project skipped over the pom but failed to build successfully. Tried adding the  tag to the dependency, but didn't work.

How did you call the deploy:deploy-file mojo? Can you try like as this: mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dpackaging="zip" -DrepositoryId="{feedName}" -Durl="{feedURL}" -DgroupId="{groupId}" -DartifactId="{artifactId}" -Dversion="{version}" -Dfile="{fileLocalPath}"?

Yes. The way I used the mojo is quite similar to your example:
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.adobe.cloud.translation.connector -DartifactId=lionbridge-connector.all.author -Dversion=5.1.1 -Dpackaging=zip -Dfile=/path-to/lionbridge-connector.all.author-5.1.1.zip -Durl=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-organization/project-id/_packaging/azure-feed/maven/v1 -DrepositoryId=azure-feed -DgeneratePom=false

As far as I know, you can set the parameter -DgeneratePom=false when a POM files is existing in the directory where you run the deploy:deploy-file mojo, otherwise you need to let to be true so that the mojo can generate a POM file on-the-fly based on other parameters you set on the mojo. @CristianMocofanescu

The strange thing is, it's extracting the pom file from the archive regardless of the -DgeneratePom parameter. If the archive is alone in a directory, the pom appears after running the mvn deploy:deploy-file command.

Try delete the POM file in the ZIP, then try the deploy:deploy-file mojo again. @CristianMocofanescu

I tried it, but the build fails when it tries to start the lionbridge connector.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.adobe.aem:aemanalyser-maven-plugin:1.5.8:project-analyse (analyser) on project project-all-container: Content Package Converter Exception Content Package Converter exception Cannot invoke "org.apache.jackrabbit.vault.packaging.PackageId.getGroup()" because "currentId" is null 

When you publish the Maven package as ZIP to Nexus, what commands and configurations did you use?  @CristianMocofanescu

I believe the artifact was manually uploaded to Nexus via its UI, so no mvn deploy command was executed. I think that's why Nexus allows artifacts without POM files. Maven doesn't. I managed to resolve it by setting -DgeneratePom=true. This generated a default POM file for the archive.

It seems I couldn't upload the artifact for lionbridge-connector successfully was because I wasn't using the parameter -DgeneratePom correctly.
Nexus is a lot more permissive when it comes to managing artifact versions and allows uploading manually even without POM files. Maven deploy doesn't allow that, however. A POM file must be present for each version. lionbridge-connector is a .zip archive without a POM. If you try deploying it via mvn deploy:deploy-file with -DgeneratePom=false, Maven will actually extract the POM from the archive META-INF. This was mainly the cause for the error, the bad POM file.
What I had to do was set -DgeneratePom=true to allow Maven to generate a default POM file for my .zip archive. This has solved my issue.
